# Fastest way to populate a matrix using row/column indicies stored in vectors

Tags: r, apply

I'm trying to do something that seems relatively straightforward to do with something apply-esque, but I can only get it to work using a for loop.

The general idea is I have two vectors, with one vector corresponding to a row in the matrix and another vector corresponding to the column, both the same length. I start with a 0 matrix, and increment [row,column] based on the pair of values in the two vectors. For example:

```
vectorCols <- c(1,2,3,1,3)
vectorRows <-  c(2,1,2,3,2)
countMat <- matrix(rep(0,9),ncol=3)
```

And at the end, `countMat` is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    0
[2,]    1    0    2
[3,]    1    0    0
```

This is pretty manageable with a `for` loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(vectorCols)){
  countMat[vectorRows[i],vectorCols[i]] <- countMat[vectorRows[i],vectorCols[i]] + 1
}
```

But I can't help thinking there is a better way to do this in R. I've tried using the `apply` family of functions, but these don't cooperate well when you want to assign something. I know I could use `mapply` and build each element of `countMat` one value at a time, but this seems inefficient--`vectorRows` and `vectorCols` are very long, and it seems wasteful to fully traverse them an entire time for each cell in `countMat`. But other than a loop and `mapply`, I can't think of how to do this. I've considered using `assign` with one of the `apply` family, but there's a caveat--my matrix actually has names for the columns and rows, with the names stored in `vectorCols` and `vectorRows`, and it seems `assign` doesn't want to play well something like `countMat["rowName"]["columnName"] (not to mention that`apply` will still want to return a value for each step in the iteration).

Any suggestions? I'd also be curious if there is an ideal way to do this if I don't have names for the vector columns and rows. If that's the case then maybe I can convert `vectorCols` and `vectorRows` to numbers, then build the matrix, then rename everything.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some solutions.  No packages are needed.

**1) table**

```
table(vectorRows, vectorCols)
```

giving:

```
          vectorCols
vectorRows 1 2 3
         1 0 1 0
         2 1 0 2
         3 1 0 0
```

Note that if there is any row or column with no entries then it will not appear.

**2) aggregate**

```
ag <- aggregate( Freq ~ ., data.frame(Freq = 1, vectorRows, vectorCols), sum)
countMat[as.matrix(ag[-3])] <- ag[[3]]
```

giving:

```
> countMat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    0
[2,]    1    0    2
[3,]    1    0    0
```

**3) xtabs**

```
xtabs(~ vectorRows + vectorCols)
```

giving:

```
          vectorCols
vectorRows 1 2 3
         1 0 1 0
         2 1 0 2
         3 1 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you! (Ignore the comments I just deleted if you saw them :) ). All three methods work, and the table method is giving me zeroed-out columns too...